# Class name changes in html

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, web-deployment

I was web-scraping and kept getting a NoSuchElement error(once every 2 or 3 successfull attempts) even though i knew the element was always there,it was an e-commerce website and it was the element in which the name of the product was stored.And after a long period of frustration and 100 failed solutions i realized that the class name of that element sometimes changes,and i would like to know why.The html code is identitcal,just the class name is different.

[image: That class change it's name]

Comment: Because that's how the website programmers decided to write the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes elements with an apparently identical structure may change either to update of the website or to specific positioning of certain elements in the grid.

For example I assume that the first card of a grid has a different h2 class due to the orange banner below, which may require a different padding value respect to other titles with other classes.

If you're looking for the titles of the products you can identify an element using something like `.card-section-mid h2` instead, bypassing the need of using a specific class name.

Thus you'd need to do something like:

```
title = card.find_element_by_css_selector('.card-section-mid h2')
#card assuming you've already selected the card element
```

The best solution in web-scraping is to look for an API instead.

The second best solution is to find such strong selectors that will survive the test of time or the variability of the layout. In this case it seems the the first h2 contained in the `div.card-section-mid` always contain the title. Thus is a favorite target to select for web-scraping purposes.

Comment: funny this is,card section mid also changes sometimes

Comment: Yeah, that's part of the game with web-scraping hahah. Try to find the best performant, most universal selector to fit your needs :)

For example if even `.card-section-mid` isn't found in every card, you can try to do `card.find_element_by_css_selector('h2 a')`. Even though you might have some unwanted elements now.

Comment: And there's no way around it?

Comment: Edited my prev comment

Comment: That finds the first `h2` tag with and `a` tag in it?

Comment: Close! It finds the first a tag under the h2 tag, which is good cause the a tag contains the title of the shop item. So even if there are three h2 tags in the card, I’m gonna look just to the one containing the a tag. And vicevicersa I’m not gonna take any random anchor links if it’s not a child of a h2 tag